# build a graph when elements of different paths has same names

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given is unfortunately a data table like this:

```
Group Category
A       1
B       2 
A       2
```

I want to build a graph whereas the start is the category and the groups are assigned. The result shall look like

```
1 - A
2 - B
  - A
```

A is part of every graph. When I use merge e.g. like

```
        MATCH (g:Group {Group: "A"), (c:Category {Category: "1")
        MERGE (g) -[:BELONGS_TO]- (c)
        RETURN g,c
```

I create those graphs with one Node A connected to both Cat 1/2. But I want to have Node A twice which have an edge to Cat1 and Cat2 each - none is connected to both Cat's. The Merge checks if the Node A already exists (which he does after the first Merge) and connects it than to CAT 2 instead of creating a new Node A for CAT 2 (absoltely correct but not what I am trying to achieve).

If there would'nt be the same Groupname this would work easily.

Anyone has a hint for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `CREATE` if you don't want duplicates:

```
MATCH (c:Category {Category: "1")
CREATE (g:Group {Group: "A") -[:BELONGS_TO]-> (c)
RETURN g,c
```

(You were also missing an end to your arrow so I added it where I thought it should go)

Comment: Problem is, that the MATCH searches for a NODE A. After the first run there is a NODE A (either created or merged with UUID 1) connected to CAT 1. When the CAT 2 is in the loop it finds NODE A (with UUID 1) again with MATCH and makes a new edge to CAT 2 so that NODE A is connected to CAT 1 and CAT 2. Required is NODE A - CAT1 and NODE A (different UUID but same name) - CAT2. Sorry if that is confusing .. but I need for every entry in the table with Name A a new NODE as they should be different graphs. Unfortnately they have named the Groups the same but they are different categories.

Comment: Oh, right, of course.  I've just edited.  You can put the `Group` definition into the `CREATE` to say that you want that to be created fresh every time

Comment: Awesome. I replaced the CREATE by MERGE to avoid having more than one NODE A per graph - it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, I see, I think I still misunderstood a bit but I get it now.  Glad it helped! ;)